# How do I find the file containing a ComVisible class registered using regasm?

Tags: com, comvisible

I have written a class in C# and marked it ComVisible.  I uploaded it to my customer's computer and registered it using RegAsm.  But when I try to use it from a Python script, I get an error saying "The system cannot find the file specified."  If I replace the name of the class with "ThisDoesNotExist.ReportEngine", the error message is "Invalid class string", which is what I would expect.  So, it appears that the Python script found the class name ("CrystalReportsRT2.ReportEngine", in case anyone cares) in the registry, but could not find the DLL file containing that class.

If I was working with an old-fashioned COM object, I could find the class name in the registry, note its CLSID, find the registry entry for that CLSID, and file name from the InProcServer32 key.  But for a class registered using RegAsm, the InProcServer32 key only contains the class name and other assembly information.  How can I find out what file is being looked for so I can verify its existence?  Or do I have to add the assembly into the Global Assembly Cache?

I was trying to get a modified version of an existing library to work.  I decided to try a brand-new library.  I tried this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RegAsmTest
{
    [Guid("E476213F-1D62-408C-B89E-D9A8B4814CE1")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ITest
    {
        int DoSomething(int input);
    }

    [Guid("C1E26B60-7D25-4EFE-80E9-F958024E22ED")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("RegAsmTest.Test")]
    public class Test : ITest
    {
        public int DoSomething(int input)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Input was {}", input));
            return input;
        }
    }
}
```

And I tried using it from Python:

```
import win32com.client

try:
    TestObject = win32com.client.Dispatch("RegAsmTest.Test")
    print ("Object created.")
except Exception as ex:
    print ("Failed to create object: " + str(ex))
```

At first I got "Class not registered".  I checked to see if I had "Register for COM Interop" checked, and I hadn't.  I checked it.  I got another error.  (I'm sorry, but I've forgotten which.)  I tried running RegAsm with /tlb, and I got "System cannot find the file specified."  I tried unregistering the library, and got "Invalid class string" where I would have expected "Class not registered".  I tried re-registering without /tlb, and got "System cannot find the file specified".

So, I've got three different errors, and I do not know what sequence of operations or missed operations cause them:
Class not registered
Invalid class string
System cannot find the file specified

What do I have to do?

Comment: If you didn't put it in the GAC then you need to use regasm's /codebase option.  SysInternals' Process Monitor utility is useful to see this stuff go wrong.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That was the problem.  But to further my understanding:  what good does calling regasm with no options do?  It added an entry for the class in the registry, but without any information on where to find it.  It apparently did not put the class into the GAC, because my Python script couldn't find it.

Comment: COM has a very nasty DLL Hell problem, registration is machine-wide.  So if you make a change to the library then any program that uses it is going to be affected.  Which goes wrong when one program gets recompiled to use the changed library but other(s) don't.  The GAC solves it by being able to store multiple versions of the library, programs that are not recompiled can still find and use the old library and putter along instead of crashing in a hard to diagnose way.

Comment: Thank you.  That much I understand.  But don't I have to use gacutil to put a library into the GAC?  The thing I'm curious about is what benefit there is to running regasm without any options.  That doesn't put the library into the GAC, does it?  And if it doesn't put the library into the GAC, what does it do?  Having an entry in the registry without a codebase key doesn't seem to do enable a client to find the library.  Or at least, it didn't for me.

Comment: It just writes registry keys so the client compiler and program can find the library back.  Avoiding DLL Hell is normally only necessary on the user's machine.  But it doesn't stop you from solving it on your own machine, in which case you'd consider gacutil.  But for normal development work you'd always use /codebase, like the IDE does.